# Android - sqlite reading value in table with comma, WHERE clause

Tags: android, sqlite

So this is value on my database, "COLUMN_days" is the column name..

```
     days
 ==> Mon
 ==> Mon,Tue,Wed
 ==> Mon,Fri
```

So here is my code for selecting a value.

```
 getDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " 
       + ALARM_TABLE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_days + " = " + "'Tue'", null);
```

But it didn't display the value in database that have a Tue, because I want to read the database all the word "Tue" that have in database. For example I want to display all the "Tue" in database, It will display the "Mon,Tue,Wed" or I want to display all the "Mon" then It will display the three "Mon" that I have in database.

I hope you understand what I want to know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd better **normalize** your database. Each column should contain a **single** value and data shouldn't be **redundant**. You may relate columns from more tables.

Comment: Normalise your data structure first and do not have multiple values stored within a single text value.

Answer (score 1):

Use `like` operator with `%` instead `'=' operator` as in

```
getDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " 
       + ALARM_TABLE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_days + " like " + "'%Tue%'", null);
```

Comment: It works, OK. But this is really just a workaround to handle a **terribly designed** database.